# Github actions echo command not creating file

Tags: github-actions

I'm in the process of moving a working CircleCI workflow over to Github Actions.

I'm running:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

container: 
  image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
```

I run the following command:

```
echo ${{ secrets.GCLOUD_API_KEYFILE }} > ./gcloud-api-key.json
```

Before running this command, **gcloud-api-key.json** has not yet been created. This command works in CircleCI but in Github Actions I get the error:

> /__w/_temp/asd987as89d7cf.sh: 2: /__w/_temp/asd987as89d7cf.sh: type:: not found

Does anyone know what this error means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason was because my secret key was more then 1 line long. Once I made it one line it worked.

Comment: And how you echo things that are more than 1 line long?

Answer (score 3):

In order to use secrets which contain more than just one line (like secret jsons) one has to save the base64 encoded secret in Github which makes it one line.
On linux the encoding is done via:

```bash
cat mysecret.json | base64
```

Then in the action you need to decode it using

```bash
echo ${{ secrets.YOUR_SECRET }} | base64 -d > secret.json
```

Comment: P.S. If you want the base64 to output with no Enter lines, do 
cat mysecret.json | base64 -w 0

Answer (score 0):

Use quotation marks for `echo` command:

```yaml
run: echo "${{ secrets.YOUR_SECRET }}" > secret_file
```